# Amazon pay sandbox redirection url updation

Tags: amazon-pay

Using test buyer account created from amazon pay sandbox to test from local. The redirection url given earlier was'http://localhost/xxxxx'.  Modified it later into http://localhost/yyyy' and added in the list of return url for the registered application. But the page is still getting redirected to old page(xxxx) after login.
Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the JavaScript for the widgets that contains the redirectURL parameter?

Comment: Got it working correctly after few days also cleared the browser cache